# SQL Query with multiple tables to fetch data from one table and populate in another

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables `A` and `B`. Table A has the columns as `PersonID`, `MobileNumber`, `PersonName` where `PersonID` and `MobileNumber` are unique columns. Table B has he columns as `ReportID`, `PersonID`, `Details` with `ReportID` as unique column.

Each person can add any number of Reports with different `ReportID`. Now my Table B has many reports and I want to add the `MobileNumber` column to it. But Table B has many entries for a single person. What query can I use to take the `MobileNumber` from Table A and populate it to Table B with respect to each `PersonID`? The query should take `MobileNumber` from Table A and then add it to Table B across the `PersonID` column.

**EXAMPLE**

**Table A**

```
PersonID   |   MobileNumber   |   PersonName
   P1           9999999999           John
   P2           8888888888           Mack
   P3           7777777777           Jack
   P4           6666666666           Mike
```

**Table B**

```
ReportID   |   PersonID   |   Details   |   MobileNumber
   R1             P1           .....
   R2             P2           .....
   R3             P2           .....
   R4             P3           .....
   R5             P3           .....
   R6             P3           .....
   R7             P4           .....
   R8             P4           .....
```

What is the query I can use to populate mobile number and get the result as below?

**EXPECTED RESULT**

```
ReportID   |   PersonID   |   Details   |   MobileNumber
   R1             P1           .....         9999999999
   R2             P2           .....         8888888888
   R3             P2           .....         8888888888
   R4             P3           .....         7777777777
   R5             P3           .....         7777777777
   R6             P3           .....         7777777777
   R7             P4           .....         6666666666
   R8             P4           .....         6666666666
```

PS:
I don't want to select the values as new table. I want to populate the values in the original table itself using UPDATE

Comment: You can achieve this by inner join

Comment: @ManoPrathibhanC Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating `DhruvJoshi's` and `Mittal's` answer I was able to use the query below that works for my case.

```
UPDATE TableB
SET MobileNumber = A.MobileNumber
FROM TableB AS B
INNER JOIN
TableA AS A ON B.PersonID = A.PersonID
INNER JOIN
TableB ON A.PersonID = TableB.PersonID
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using below query:

```
UPDATE B
INNER JOIN A ON A.PersonID = B.PersonID
SET B.MobileNumber = A.MobileNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a JOIN statement to achieve this. More specifically LEFT OUTER JOIN like below

```
SELECT B.*, A.MobileNumber
FROM TableB B LEFT OUTER JOIN
TableA A on B.PersonID=A.PersonID
```

> I don't want to select the values as new table. I want to populate the values in the original table itself using UPDATE
>   Based on this you may use statements like below

```
ALTER TABLE TableB
  ADD MobileNumber VARCHAR(50)
GO
```

You need to fire above ALTER statement if the column does not exists in TableB

```
UPDATE B
SET
B.MobileNumber= A.MobileNumber
FROM TableB B LEFT OUTER JOIN
TableA A on B.PersonID=A.PersonID
```